# JQuery UI Datepicker slide title and dates on month change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get my Calendar to work. I am currently using the JQuery UI datepicker and I am quite happy with it. But I don't use it as a picker in a Textbox, I use it 'standalone'.

And I am trying to achieve a slide effect, when I change the month. But i don't want to slide the whole calendar. I just want to slide the title and the dates itself, not the next / previous buttons and not the weekdays.

First I tried this:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
    $(".ui-datepicker").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
}
```

and obviously the whole calendar is moving. But trying to slide the title only by changing **.ui-datepicker** to **.ui-datepicker-title**, nothing happens.
And I think it would look quite strange, if it had worked. Because the title would be moving to the right while disappearing, and the new title would come in. 
But what I want to achieve is an effect, like it slides behind the next "button" and the new month and year comes in from behind the previous button.

It is hard to describe, so watch this animation I made. I want to achieve something like this:
http://gifmaker.me/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2014031022viCiUrQHvGuK1MAVDKd4ve&file=output_UagFEZ.gif
(The design is already complete and works. The anmation is the problem)

Is this possible with the datepicker? I haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 0):

**try this work perfectly:**

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            $(".ui-datepicker").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 600);

     }
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But as I said: This is not the effect I want. It moves the whole calendar module. Not just the title (and dates).

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?